# How to import knitr cache into the global environment of R session

Tags: r, caching, knitr

I created an R markdown (.rmd) which contains 20 R chunks, some of which are cached, when the file is knitted. After knitting, the global environment of R is still empty. How do I import the content from a cached chunk into the global environment of R without running the code for a second time?

Comment: Whoever voted down, please tell me what is bad